# SSL client verification failure

Tags: ssl, keystore, apigee, truststore, ca

I have a backend server with SSL only as defaut public interface. This server listens on 443 with cert, key and ca files on, ssl verify client is set to true.

On client side, I have client cert, key and a ca file made of 2 CA files catted together (intermediate CA, root CA) in a single ca.pem file. When I do curl request on my backend server, it works fine. I also tested the server / client cert and key with gnutls-serv and openssl s_server to ensure all was valid.

But when I create a keystore on Apigee (client cert and key file [pem format]) and a trustore (ca.pem file), there is an error: 
- target.name        fsbca-test
- Properties
- Expression         ("fsbca-test" equals target.name)
- ExpressionResult   true
- Tree               TARGET_fsbca-test
- error            The Service is temporarily unavailable
- error.cause        General SSLEngine problem
- error.cause.cause  General SSLEngine problem
- error.class        com.apigee.messaging.adaptors.http.HttpAdaptorException
- state            TARGET_REQ_FLOW
- type         ErrorPoint

If I put SSL verify client to false on my backend, then the request is correctly diverted by Apigee and I get the response.

If I put  IgnoreValidationErrors to true in the target endpoints property, then the request is diverted to my backend server but I can see an error in the server's log: "client sent no required SSL certificate while reading c...".

Any ideas about what could be wrong in what I am doing?

Additional track: could it be an issue on Apigee side with the CA file made of 2 certs (it may ignore trailing certificates found in a .pem). If wanted to test pkcs12 and jks but I failed to upload them to Apigee (the API doc page only describes .pem, JAR and cert action). I wrote a small Java client with pkcs12 keystore and jks trustore and it worked fine from my local workstation.

Thank you in advance for any piece of information that could help me.

Regards

Fr

Comment: Can you add your TargetEndpoint/SSLInfo configuration?

Comment: <SSLInfo>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ClientAuthEnabled>true</ClientAuthEnabled>
            <KeyStore>FsbcaKeystore</KeyStore>
            <KeyAlias>FsbcaKey</KeyAlias>
          <!-- remove in prod -->
          <IgnoreValidationErrors>true</IgnoreValidationErrors>
          <TrustStore>FsbcaTruststore</TrustStore> 
        </SSLInfo>

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your certificates separately (one per cert), and you need the entire trust chain of certificates to be stored in your truststore.

[Here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers) is the page about SSL to your backend.

EDIT:
Here is a method I know works:

1) Separate certs into separate PEM files. Do not put more than once cert in a file.

2) Validate each cert using openssl:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert file name>
```

Validate that no certs are expired, and that the Subject and Issuer fields create a chain of all the certs, with identical names.

The server's certificate, the root certificate, and all certificates in between need to be in the truststore.

Comment: I already read this page and this was working with self signed cert. But with ca, this is not working as expected. I put client cert and key in the keystore, and I put ca (2 files catted) in trustore. My backend server uses the same ca file as the ssl_client_certificate.

Comment: My truststore is now made of {
  "certs" : [ "TrustServ", "TrustFsbca", "TrustMbca" ],
  "keys" : [ ],
  "name" : "FsbcaTruststore"
} but it still fails with SSL engine processing error. As said, I used my client / server cert and key with CA files for testing with openssl s_client + s_server, then with gnutls, then with nginx and curl (with no -k) option and it works. I really dont understand what is the expected configuration to run the said configuration. In the trust store (first alias is my server cert, fsbca is the intermediate ca and mbca is the root ca. Regards

Comment: That error can happen if the target cannot validate your client cert. When you use curl to test directly against your backend, can you successfully communicate when you only present the client cert and not the entire trust chain of certs for the client? If your curl communication needs the entire trust chain, you can concatenate the entire trust chain of certs into a single pem file for presenting to the target. (Until I researched your problem, I wasn't aware this was allowed.) Either that, or add the trust chain on the target itself.

Comment: There is no problem on my target backend: with curl, if no CA is set, then I see the correct error in nginx error's log. The problem is on the CA cert chain on Apigee backend side. When client verify is set to on, there is no request sent to my backend but an SSL engine processing error on Apigee side.

Comment: There would be no request sent through to the backend if the SSL handshake failed. My recommendation is to have Apigee support help debug your specific setup. Sorry I couldn't figure out your issue!

Comment: Thanks in anycase for your time. Regards.